# Android components-based application design: How should I represent this model?

Tags: android, components

I would like to re-design my application into components, so it is more modular and easier to re-use in the future, but I've never really designed applications, so I don't really know how I should do this.

Here is a brief description of the application:

- The purpose of the Application is to allow the User to create "Events" that are going to be stored locally on the Device and sent over the network.
- The User can interact with the application through 2 Activities: A "NewEventActivity" that allows him to create the new Events and a "LogbookActivity" that allows him to browse previously created Events.
- The local storage should be handled by a SQLite Database
- The Event should be sent in a specific Binary format.
- Other applications should be able to Use the Sending component to Format and send other type of messages in the same format.

This drawing represents how I was thinking of organizing the components. Boxes represent components, and arrows represent interactions without those components.
[image]

Here are my questions:

- Does this model look OK? Can you see something that could be improved?
- Should my SQLiteHelper be a ContentProvider or a ContentResolver?
- Should I create one BroadcastReceiver class per type of Signal, or should I create one big BroadcastReceiver that handles all the kind of Signals my application can handle?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions to simplify the design:

- If `EventWriter` and `EventReader` only interact with the activity due to direct user interaction, they don't need to be `BroadcastReceivers`.  In fact, they could just be methods in the activities.
- Depending on how you choose when to send Events, you could also refactor `MessageFormatter` and `Sender` into an `IntentService` which will periodically poll the content provider and choose which pieces of data to send.  You can schedule the `IntentService` via alarms.

> Should my SQLiteHelper be a
>   ContentProvider or a ContentResolver?

It should implement ContentProvider (since it provides access to data).

> Should I create one BroadcastReceiver
>   class per type of Signal, or should I
>   create one big BroadcastReceiver that
>   handles all the kind of Signals my
>   application can handle?

I lean towards one receiver per signal type, but that's really just a preference.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
EventWriter and EventReader are methods of the Activities at the moment, I want to dissociate them because my app is actually more complex, and I have several activities using it. (and maybe in the future this should be available from other apps).
The Events have to be sent in real time so I cannot use IntentService.